# How to manage shared resources in iOS team development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, version-control

I'm starting a new small study project and I will work together with a friend. We will work on the same project, but on different parts. Sometimes we will need to modify files that are common.

My question is: how do you guys manage this kind of project? My biggest concern is about storyboard file and some other shared resources.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of things you can do here and not all of them are absolute, so here are a few of my opinions.

1. Use Git. Most simply would be to use a service like github or bitbucket.
2. Each person should create new branches for grouping all the commits for a particular change/feature and then merge the feature branches into your release branch.
3. Have a good gitignore, [here is github's objective-c gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore) as an example.
4. If your team will be growing or there is a good chance you will be working on the same pieces at the same time, don't use storyboards or xibs in general. These are a really bummer when you have merge conflicts and generally don't behave well with multiple people working on them. I recommend laying out all of your UIs in code either with autolayout or without. This in my experience also makes UIs way easier to debug, refactor, and update.

Comment: Storyboards are after all XML files. Unless you are working on the same View controller chances of it getting conflicted are less.

Comment: Which is what I said in my comment. They also don't behave like normal XML files. Often times, moving a single thing will make 5-10 different versioning and autolayout changes in a bunch of different places, making it really hard to see what has actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

@Dima mentioned that NIB files are hard to merge, this also applies to project files. Some ways to deal with this:

1. Lay out the whole file and class structure ahead of time
2. Have a single member of the team who is responsible for maintaining project structure, and if anyone wants to add/move/rename a file they get the "project master" to do it
3. Divide the app up into a series of different static library projects, and assign one person to each

Using static libraries is one of those things that is *much much* harder than it should be, but once you figure out the right combination of obscure changes to XCode's build settings everything works well.

In a nutshell, you need to

1. In the static library set "skip install" to `YES`, and make all header files public
2. In any projects using the library link it in in "build phases" and add a header search path so it knows where to look for the header files.

See the following links for the step by step:

- The best HOWTO for iOS static libraries: http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules
- Then, the first error you'll encounter is probably "header files not found". Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependency).
- If you have a project that needs to use resources like images or NIB files you need to add a `.bundle` target. Instructions [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/).

You could also use a dependency management system like [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) to automate some of this static library configuration and build. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781087/1161906).

Finally, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875019/1161906) also has an interesting approach to avoiding `xcproject` conflicts: instruct git to "always union" the merge. Haven't tried this myself.