# ios 2 different 3rd party frameworks that contain the same symbol

Tags: ios, frameworks, duplicates, symbols

In my project I use two 3rd party frameworks that both use internally `SBJSONParser` and when building a `ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser` error is raised.

**Note:** I don't have access to sources of any of the two frameworks.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2910385/1372503

Comment: Yep, your answers lead me to a solution