# Conflicting the API's of Google for Google Drive And Picasa

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api, picasa

i am working with an iOS application in which i have to use Google Drive API and Picasa Api in my application. Google Drive Library 
libGTLTouchStaticLib.a  and  picasa library libGDataTouchStaticLib.a. when i used both in my application i get the 204 duplicates symbols in my application.

This is the error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.request_ in:

/Users/bettermac9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PicBackMan-bkstztcwwtsutvgoumkwpscfvaiv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)

/Users/bettermac9/Desktop/copy latest/PicBackMan 3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
```

Please tell me that how can i remove this error and run my application without any duplicate symbol.

Comment: i found the answer : if you remove -objc_all-load from the other linker flags it works well.

Comment: Please look at this, I hope it will solve your problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910205/how-to-handle-duplicate-symbol-error-from-3rd-party-libraries