# iOS duplicate symbols from different versions of the same library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, duplicate-symbol

App A requires third-party libraries B and C. Both B and C include different versions of library D (from a further third-party).
No third-party source code is available.
This will give duplicate symbol errors when linking the app.

What solutions are available?

---

Related question involving identical libraries, allowing one copy to simply be deleted: [How to handle duplicate symbol error from 3rd party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910205/476716)

Comment: The answer given is a perfectly valid approach. What's the problem in using it?

Comment: If the two versions of the library are not binary compatible, then removing one copy will break the code relying on it.

Comment: There aren't a lot of approaches you can take in that case - you would have to merge B & D into a shared framework exposing only the classes that B provides; then do the same for C & D then you should be able to link B & C to A; I don't know how the objective-c run-time would behave in that case, though. It's an approach I use for C/C++ libraries but I've never tried it with objective-c. Plus, I don't know if the objective-c run-time would do the right thing in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by renaming the conflicting symbols in B (and its version of D if separate).
This can be done directly on the binary as long as the renames are the same length as the originals (e.g. by reversing the library prefix).

```perl
local $/ = "\0";
open my $fh, '<+', $library;
binmode $fh;

while (my $field = <$fh>) {
    my $length = length $field;
    chomp $field;

    if (defined $translation{$field}) {
        seek $fh, -$length, SEEK_CUR;
        print $fh $translation{$field};
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more how we can use this ?

Comment: @KrishnaKumar this is a snippet of Perl demonstrating how to rename symbols directly on the binary file. The hash `%translation` should already exist, and contain the desired remapping.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.